# aSmack MUC testing basics

Tags: asmack

I am developing a test chat client app using asmack. First, I am trying to test the multi-user functionality using MultiUserChat class. Basically, my aim is to check the memory & cpu footprint when I am doing a multiuser chat. I am just at very initial stage so I don't have a very fancy UI developed right now. Most of the work I want to do is progrmatically so that I can just get my memory & cpu footprint.

- Which xmpp server can I connect to do my development testing for MUC and other XMPP features?
- Do u have any sample code that I could refer to?

Let me know if any more details are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use the Openfire server it's free and easy to setup on a local machine using 127.0.0.1 and also updating your hosts file in windows if needs be

There are a [multitude of openfire tutes on the web](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=test%20openfire%20on%20local%20machine&oq=test%20openfire%20on%20local%20machine&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j69i62l3.5367j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=install%20openfire%20on%20windows%20localhost&safe=off)

1. There is MUC sample code all over the net as well, check out the docs on the [smack community site](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/extensions/muc.html)

Also go over the smack forums on the igniterealtime community site

With android and aSmack don't forget to init static classes by either calling

```
Class.forName(org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.class.getName(), true, ctx.getClassLoader());
```

or initializing all static classes

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
SmackAndroid asmk = SmackAndroid.init(context);
```

Comment: you need to init static classes because davlik vm does not utilize META-INF files that the java java vm does to init the smack providers